# WPS OFFICE ICONS LIBRARY

Tags: wps-office

I just faced an issue after installing wps on my machine. I am unable to see icons library button on wps office. AN error msg showing that my wps's some formula might not displayed due to missing somthing. Can anyone help me how to get rid of this problem. Thanks in advanced

Comment: Please add more details to this question. It's hard to help you, when you don't provide any useful information. Could you please tell what this error message is saying? What Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: I need to add icons on my docs. I have seen that wps office has by default icons library. When i installed wps office i could not even find icons liobrary option. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and i downloaded the latest wps .dev file from their official site